# Is it possible to use a databricks notebook output as my data source in Power BI?

Tags: pyspark, powerbi, databricks, spark-notebook

I would like to know if it's possible to use a databricks notebook output as my data source in Power BI. I don't want to export it to csv first.

I tried creating a connection to databricks from Power BI and got a list of all the tables available. However, I would like to use a specific notebook's output as the data source. Is that even possible without having to export it to csv?

Comment: Can you save that notebook output to a table and then connect to DBR from power bi and use that table as a source?